# Weeks between 2 mysql formatted datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am creating a Top 30 Music Chart..

Hw do I get the number of weeks between two mysql formatted datetimes? like

From: `2013-01-15 11:41:14`

Current Datetime: `2013-02-25 13:41:14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the times using `strtotime`

```
$difference = strtotime($first_date)-strtotime($second_date);

$weeks = round($difference / 604800 );
```

Comment: How do i remove the negative sign beside the week? like `-4`

Comment: @Ken you are probably subtracting small-great so subtract greater-smaller

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL is better, but in php it'll be something like this:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-15 11:41:14');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-25 13:41:14');
$interval  = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$diff      = $interval->format('%d');
echo (int)$diff/7;
```

Comment: These more modern classes are probably the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` method, then count difference between current time and time you have in your MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db_time_a = strtotime('2013-01-15 11:41:14');
$db_time_b = strtotime('2013-02-25 13:41:14');

$seconds_in_between = $db_time_a - $db_time_b;

$hours = (int)($seconds_in_between/60/60);
$minutes = (int)($seconds_in_between/60)-$hours*60;
$seconds = (int)$seconds_in_between-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;

echo 'The time in seconds in between the two times is: '.$seconds_in_between.' (Hours:'.$hours.', Minutes:'.$minutes.', Seconds:'.$seconds.')';
?>
```

You can just chunk down the seconds with "remainder" and find out the minutes (and it's remaining seconds) and so on until you hit the time-distance you want.

Answer (score 0):

does the `WEEK()` function helps you in your query ?

I don't know Mysql very well but lets assume the following :

```
select WEEK(date1-date2) from mytable where name='Ken';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DATEDIFF(date1, date2) function in mysql.
DATEDIFF() will return you the no of date between two given date. Hope you can easily get the weeks from output.